# How to expand table rows with jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Currently I have the table that is presented as the image shows with the hidden even rows. What I am looking for is that all the rows are hidden and the name of the month appears.

In the example of the image it would only have to appear November and when displaying it would have that the information for that month will appear. I am using jexpand plugin from jquery

I leave the code so that you can see how I currently have it. Any ideas?

SCRIPT

```php
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("#report tr:odd").addClass("odd");
                $("#report tr:not(.odd)").hide();
                $("#report tr:first-child").show();
                $("#report tr.odd").click(function(){
                $(this).next("tr").toggle();
                $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
            });
        });
```

CSS

```css
body { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; font-size:0.8em;}
#report { border-collapse:collapse;}
#report h4 { margin:0px; padding:0px;}
#report img { float:right;}
#report ul { margin:10px 0 10px 40px; padding:0px;}
#report th { background:#7CB8E2 url(../img/header_bkg.png) repeat-x scroll center left; color:#fff; padding:7px 15px; text-align:center;}
#report td { background:#C7DDEE none repeat-x scroll center left; color:#000; padding:7px 15px; }
#report tr.odd td { background:#fff url(../img/row_bkg.png) repeat-x scroll center left; cursor:pointer; }
#report div.arrow { background:transparent url(../img/arrows.png) no-repeat scroll 0px -16px; width:16px; height:16px; display:block;}
#report div.up { background-position:0px 0px;}
```

HTML

```html
 <table id="report" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm text-center" style="width:35%; margin:auto;">
            
                <thead class= "text-center table-info">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Calls</th>
                        <th>Sales</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php for($i = 0; $i < count($calls); ++$i) { ?>
                        <tr class="text-center">
                            <td id="id"><?= $calls[$i]['date'] ;?></td>
                            <td id="database"><?= $calls[$i]['calls'] ;?></td>
                            <td id="total"><?= $calls[$i]['sales'] ;?></td>
                            <td><div class="arrow"></div></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

[image: table]

Comment: Please elaborate more  on issue which you facing in  your current code .

Comment: The problem is that it shows the entire month of November in the example and what I am looking for is that all those rows are contained in the name of the month and when expanding they can be seen. Was it understood a little better what I am looking for?

Comment: so you mean `all rows` should be shown when click on first `tr` which has same month data ?

Comment: exactly that.
October ↓ ↑
202010 xx
202010 xx
202010 xx
202010 xx
November ↓ ↑
202011 xx
202011 xx

December ↓ ↑
202012 xx
202012 xx
202012 xx
202012 xx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your dates are display in `dd-mm-yyyy` so easy way to get month is to use `split` method then once we get month we need to loop through `trs` to hide all month expect the first one and also add `odd` class to it.

Then, onclick of `tr` just get the month from `td` and then loop through trs with same month add `up` class to that td and show same tr.

***Demo code***:

```js
//when tr is clicked
$(document).on("click", "#report tr.odd", function() {
  //get month 
  var mnth = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text().trim().split("-")[1]
  //loop thorough tr to find same month tr
  $("tbody >  tr").not(this).each(function() {
    var mnth_other = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text().trim().split("-")[1]
    if (mnth == mnth_other) {
      $(this).toggle();
      $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
    }

  });
});
var date_current;
//loop through tr
$("tbody >  tr").each(function() {
  //get month
  var dates = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text().trim().split("-")[1];
  //check if not equal
  if (date_current != dates) {
    $(this).addClass("odd");
    $(this).find(".arrow").addClass("down");
    date_current = dates;
  } else {
    //hide other tr
    $(this).hide()
  }

})
```

```css
.up {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.down {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.arrow {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="report" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm text-center" style="width:35%; margin:auto;">

  <thead class="text-center table-info">
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Calls</th>
      <th>Sales</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr class="text-center">
      <td id="id">
        27-11-2020
      </td>
      <td id="database">
        22
      </td>
      <td id="total">
        1
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <td id="id">
        27-11-2020
      </td>
      <td id="database">
        22
      </td>
      <td id="total">
        1
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <td id="id">
        21-11-2020
      </td>
      <td id="database">
        22
      </td>
      <td id="total">
        12
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <td id="id">
        20-12-2020
      </td>
      <td id="database">
        222
      </td>
      <td id="total">
        21
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <td id="id">
        27-12-2020
      </td>
      <td id="database">
        22
      </td>
      <td id="total">
        1
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <td id="id">
        27-12-2020
      </td>
      <td id="database">
        22
      </td>
      <td id="total">
        1
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="arrow"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried it but it does not work, it shows all the results and the arrow with the click event does not perform any function. why could this happen?

Comment: sorry, I needed to add $ (document) .ready (function () {
already works correctly, thank you so much..

Comment: I have other tables in the html and the function hides the tr from all of them, how would I have to do so that the hide method only hides those of this table

Comment: Hi ,. change `$("tbody >  tr")` to `$("#report tbody >  tr")` so only `report` tables tr will get hidden.

Comment: thank you very much. It works great. Regards